# Where do I find TerraGO GeoPDF hands-on tutorial online?

Tags: pdf

Where can I find a TerraGO GeoPDF hands-on online tutorial?

I'd like some examples I can use on my computer to learning how to use it. My agency has their toolbar on our computer system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Terrago Technologies](http://www.terragotech.com/)
Has some demo videos available.

Essentially the short version is...
 If you have terrago publisher you can write terrago geo-pdfs. If you have a terrago pdf you can use the terrago (free) toolbar with it.
This gives extra functionality for markups and saving markups with geo-reference information to be sent back to be put into the system (comes in as shapefiles unless you have the terrago arcgis server publisher extenstion).